# How to count the number when click on font-awesome icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some issues with the count when click on the font-awesome icon? When i click now on the icon the number does not change.
Here is my JSfiddle. Can anybody help me?

Here is my html

```
<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>

<i class="fa fa-heart-o btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:btnClick()"></i>
```

Javascript

```
var timesClicked = 0;

function btnClick() {
timesClicked++;

document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;
return true
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ghbhtcf/

Comment: Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/7ghbhtcf/

Comment: There is a reason why you couldn't post the link in the post, don't just ignore it

Comment: You should have posted the Code on the site and not the link.

Comment: Please refer to my answer, this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to, you could use JQuery, which would help you get what you are looking for.

```js
var timesClicked = 0;

$(".fa-heart-o").on("click",function(){
 timesClicked++;
 document.getElementById('timesClicked').innerHTML = timesClicked;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center><span id="timesClicked">0</span></center>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o btn btn-default"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

This Code Will Work. You can try this

HTML:

```
<div id="timesClicked">Number of Downloads: 0</div>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" onclick="btnClick();"></i>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var cnt = 0;
function btnClick() {
    cnt = parseInt(cnt) + parseInt(1);
    var updatedValue = document.getElementById("timesClicked");
    updatedValue.innerHTML = "Number of Downloads: " + cnt + "";
}
```

you'll need to add the css link for Font Awesome Icon. and also add

```
jquery-1.8.2.js
```

or any other version that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JQuery script to demo ... As the others mentioned

CSS Demo

```
#nav { 
    width:480px;
    margin:1em auto;
}    
#nav ul {
    margin:1em auto; 
    padding:0; 
    font:1em "Arial Black",sans-serif; 
}    
#nav ul li{
     display:inline;
}     
#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:.25em 25px; 
    background:#666; color:#ffffff;
}     
#nav ul li a:hover{
    background:#ff9900; 
    color:#ffffff;
}     
#nav ul li a.active { 
    background:#ff9900; 
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

JQuery Demo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){

    $('#nav ul li a').each(function(){
        var path = window.location.href;
        var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        if(url == current){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        };
    });         
});

</script>
```

HTML Demo

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="nav" >
      <ul>
          <li><a href='index.php?1'>One</a></li>
          <li><a href='index.php?2'>Two</a></li>
          <li><a href='index.php?3'>Three</a></li>
          <li><a href='index.php?4'>Four</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine if you load your javascript in the `<head>` or `<body>` tag.

[image]